# Can we implement a php extract function in php with out using zend api

Tags: php, scope, extract, symbol-table

Extract function of php adds variables to the local scope of the calling function. How can we write our own php function extract which does the same?

Comment: Why would you? - I don't understand the intention of the question.

Comment: I would not do that, of course. I was just thinking if there is any way to do that. Now its confirm that we cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that in pure-PHP : a function doesn't have access to the variables of its caller.

This looks like the sort of thing you'll need to write a C extension to develop -- you'll have more control over the internals of PHP variables there.

*(And I don't really see why you're trying to do that : why not just use the existing [`extract`](http://php.net/extract) function ? )*

Comment: I was just wondering if there is any pure php way of implementing extract

Answer (score 0):

[PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/) is a javascript library which contains the functions as those of php, here is its **[extract](http://phpjs.org/functions/extract:397)** function you can get an idea from. Having said that, i wonder why are you looking for your own function when php already provides one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if it is just for the fun of it it is possible:

```
<?php
$data=array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);

foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
    ${$name} = $value;
}

echo $a;
?>
```

But some problems - like conflicts with $data, $name and $value and you can't wrap it in a function. But possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,

the reason why i did this because i need something more from extract function that it should trim the values too

```
function extractArray($ar) {
        if(count($ar)>=1) {
            foreach($ar as $k=>$v) {
                $GLOBALS[$k] = (is_array($v)?$v:trim($v));
            }
        }
}
```

I just pas my $_GET, $_POST, and else arrays like this
for e.g.
$_GET['username'] = '    justnajm     ';
extractArray($_GET);

and i can just echo  and it will print 'justnajm'